# Google App Script: wide range of execution time

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple function to move the cursor to another place of the spreadsheet. Sometime this code takes 30 seconds to execute, sometimes it takes 1 second to execute, which makes it useless. Is there a way to recode it so the execution time is more consistent?

```
function go_to(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue()
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Records")
var range = sheet.getRange("B"+(active+2))
sheet.setActiveRange(range)
}
```

Comment: What is the expected value of the variable `active`?  You have not explained what the code does, or what the expected end result is.  All you need to do is add a couple of `Logger.log()` statements to see what the code is doing, and then you can determine whether you are getting an unexpected result.  Are you trying to get the value from a single cell?  If so, I would use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getCell(1, 1).getValue()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems pretty consistent in time performance for me.  How's it work on your setup?

```
    function go_to()
{
  var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rsht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Records');
  rsht.setActiveRange(rsht.getRange("B" + Number(sht.getActiveRange().getValue() + 2)));
}
```

Comment: @ Cooper. I'm not sure why there is a `if` statement in your code. All it's supposed to do is pick a value say `10` from the active cell with getValue() then move the cursor to `Records!B10`

Comment: Oh I misread your requirements.  You wanted to do this on every sheet but then move to your new position on a sheet named "records" okay I did that wrong.  I'll take a look and see how that changes the game.  Be back later...

Comment: I'm getting a little more inconsistent results here as well.  It seems that the page change is a bit less predictable.  I have a routine that builds a jstree directory tree and sometime it will run in thirty seconds and sometimes much longer.  I don't know the details behind the scenes.  So maybe we need to put up a spinning wheel to let users know were thinking about moving.